# How to write a function for concatenation in Java

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I am new to java. I java a string like this .

```
String result = "'" + city + "'" + "," + "'" + locality + "'" + "," + "'" + Name_of_Person + "'" + "," + "'"
                + User_email_address + "'" + "," + "'" + user_phone_number + "'" + "," + "'" + sub_locality + "'"
                + "," + "'" + street_name + "'" + "," + "'" + home_plot_no + "'" + "," + "'" + pin_code + "'" + ","
                + "'" + project_society_build_name + "'" + "," + "'" + landmark_reference_1 + "'" + "," + "'"
                + landmark_reference_2 + "'" + "," + "'" + No_of_Schools + "'" + "," + "'" + No_of_Hospitals + "'"
                + "," + "'" + No_of_Metro + "'" + "," + "'" + No_of_Mall + "'" + "," + "'" + No_of_Park + "'" + ","
                + "'" + Distance_of_schools + "'" + "," + "'" + Distance_of_Hospitals + "'" + "," + "'"
                + Distance_of_Metro + "'" + "," + "'" + Distance_of_Mall + "'" + "," + "'" + Distance_of_Park + "'"
                + "," + "'" + lat + "'" + "," + "'" + lng + "'" + "," + "'" + ip + "'" + "," + "'" + hostname + "'"
                + "," + "'" + ip_city + "'" + "," + "'" + ip_region + "'" + "," + "'" + ip_country + "'" + "," + "'"
                + ip_loc + "'" + "," + "'" + ip_org + "'" + "," + "'" + ip_postal + "'" + "," + "'" + home_type
                + "'" + "," + "'" + area + "'" + "," + "'" + beds + "'" + "," + "'" + bath_rooms + "'" + "," + "'"
                + building_age + "'" + "," + "'" + floors + "'" + "," + "'" + balcony + "'" + "," + "'" + amenities
                + "'" + "," + "'" + gated_security + "'" + "," + "'" + physical_security + "'" + "," + "'"
                + cctv_camera + "'" + "," + "'" + controll_access + "'" + "," + "'" + elevator + "'" + "," + "'"
                + power_back_up + "'" + "," + "'" + parking + "'" + "," + "'" + partial_parking + "'" + "," + "'"
                + onsite_maintenance_store + "'" + "," + "'" + open_garden + "'" + "," + "'" + party_lawn + "'"
                + "," + "'" + amenities_balcony + "'" + "," + "'" + club_house + "'" + "," + "'" + fitness_center
                + "'" + "," + "'" + swimming_pool + "'" + "," + "'" + party_hall + "'" + "," + "'" + tennis_court
                + "'" + "," + "'" + basket_ball_court + "'" + "," + "'" + squash_coutry + "'" + "," + "'"
                + amphi_theatre + "'" + "," + "'" + business_center + "'" + "," + "'" + jogging_track + "'" + ","
                + "'" + convinience_store + "'" + "," + "'" + guest_rooms + "'" + "," + "'" + interior + "'" + ","
                + "'" + tiles + "'" + "," + "'" + marble + "'" + "," + "'" + wooden + "'" + "," + "'"
                + modular_kitchen + "'" + "," + "'" + partial_modular_kitchen + "'" + "," + "'" + gas_pipe + "'"
                + "," + "'" + intercom_system + "'" + "," + "'" + air_conditioning + "'" + "," + "'"
                + partial_air_conditioning + "'" + "," + "'" + wardrobe + "'" + "," + "'" + sanitation_fixtures
                + "'" + "," + "'" + false_ceiling + "'" + "," + "'" + partial_false_ceiling + "'" + "," + "'"
                + recessed_lighting + "'" + "," + "'" + location + "'" + "," + "'" + good_view + "'" + "," + "'"
                + transporation_hub + "'" + "," + "'" + shopping_center + "'" + "," + "'" + hospital + "'" + ","
                + "'" + school + "'" + "," + "'" + ample_parking + "'" + "," + "'" + park + "'" + "," + "'" + temple
                + "'" + "," + "'" + bank + "'" + "," + "'" + less_congestion + "'" + "," + "'" + less_pollution
                + "'" + "," + "'" + maintenance + "'" + "," + "'" + maintenance_value + "'" + "," + "'"
                + Near_by_school + "'" + "," + "'" + Near_by_hospital + "'" + "," + "'" + Near_by_mall + "'" + ","
                + "'" + Near_by_park + "'" + "," + "'" + Near_by_metro + "'" + "," + "'" + city + "'" + "," + "'"
                + locality + "'" + "," + "'" + token + "'";
```

I concatenated many strings to one result string variable. I need to write function for this concatenation operation for code optimization.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use a csv library for this.

Comment: any example for this ??

Comment: So what *exactly* is your performance requirement, and how close does your current code come? (I'd say a far bigger issue here is readability, but that's a different matter...)

Comment: I am expecting like some function which will append the quotes and plus sign.

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach would be to use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

```
//Setup the joiner for between items
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("','");
sj.add(city);
sj.add(locality);
//[...]

//One last wrap to add initial and trailing '
String result = new StringBuilder("'").append(sj.toString()).append("'").toString();
```

However, you need to take care that the strings you add are properly escaped (' inside your strings might break your code)

If you run Java 7 still, you'd be forced to do it with StringBuilder alone:

```
public String join(String... s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("'");
    for(String token : s) {
        sb.append(token).append("','");
    }
    sb.append("'");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And call it like

```
String result = join(city, locality, Name_of_Person); //Need to add more...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work"? Maybe you don't have Java 8? Then StringJoiner would not exist yet (and you'd have to do this using StringBuilder entierly. What error do you get?

Comment: OK I am using java 7 only.It does'nt shows any error.but the data is not saved in that format.

Comment: If you have Java 7 this shouldn't even compile?!

Comment: but it complies for me.I dont know.any other way to achieve this??

Comment: Using a `StringBuilder` should not be necessary in this case. AFAIK java automatically uses `StringBuilder` to concat multiple strings. Also you can pass a prefix and suffix to `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @fabian you're right that the original code will result in compiled bytecode using StringBuilder - but the goal here is to increase readability and maintainability.

Comment: Result of `join` always ends with two apostrophes (`''`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    Object[] all = {
        city, locality, Name_of_Person, User_email_address, user_phone_number,
        sub_locality, street_name, home_plot_no, pin_code, project_society_build_name,
        // .....
    };
    String result = Stream.of(all)
        .map(x -> "'" + x + "'")
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    System.out.println(result);
```

Or

```
static String join(Object... objects) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object e : objects)
        sb.append(",").append("'").append(e).append("'");
    return sb.substring(1);
}
```

and

```
String result = join(all);
```

Comment: I am using java 7 only. dot map functions supports only in java 8

Comment: Seems like `.append(",").append("'")` could be done with a single append.